# How to set ItemsSource?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

This dialog makes no sense to me

http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/4223/50709706.gif

And I'm having trouble finding good tutorials on it. Most of the examples aren't detailed enough, or do stuff via code, but I'd like to take advantage of the IDE as much as possible.

Whats the difference between `ItemsSource` and `DataContext`?

I'd like to bind it to just a List for starters. I don't need SQL or databases or anything fancy. Where would I declare my list? In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`? How do I get it to appear in that dialog?

Comment: As an aside, I recommend taking the time to become comfortable with XAML.  There are still many things that are difficult or impossible to do from the visual designer.  XAML is more than just a way to say where the text boxes and buttons should go; it's a rich, powerful language for describing objects and their relationships.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of "DataContext" as the default value for "Source" in a binding.

When you create a binding, you can specify the path and source, like this (I'll use TextBox as an example):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Foo,Source={StaticResource Bar}}" />
```

So my TextBox.Text property is bound to a Foo property on an object called Bar (a resource somewhere in the application).

However, if you have a whole bunch of things that you want to bind to properties on Bar, it's easier to set Bar as the DataContext of the parent container. A Binding without a Source will just use the DataContext by default, and DataContext flows through to child controls from the parent. So:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource Bar}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Foo}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Fizz}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Buzz}" />
</StackPanel>
```

All of the TextBoxes are still binding to properties on Bar, but they're doing it without setting it as a Source explicitly.

So let's have another look at the dialog you posted. It's giving you several options for the "source" of the ItemsSource binding. When you choose "DataContext", you're telling Visual Studio that the ItemsControl doesn't need to know the source - it'll pick it up from the DataContext of the parent container (maybe even the Window itself).

If you chose one of the other options (ElementName, RelativeSource or StaticResource) then you'd be setting the binding's source explicitly for that ItemsControl.

Once you've told it that it's binding to the DataContext, you'll need to drop into the "Path" section of the dialog and tell it which property to bind the items of the control to. In the end, the markup would look something like this (assuming it's a ListBox):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Foos}" />
```

So the items in the ListBox are coming from a property called "Foos", and that property is on an object that's set in the DataContext somewhere higher in the logical tree (perhaps on the Window itself).

Comment: What I really don't get is when I choose `DataContext` as the source, then dropdown to `Source`, there are no options. I only see "None". Specifically where in my C# code am I supposed to put something like `List<MyClass> items` so that it will appear in the ItemsSource dialog?

Comment: The point is that if you tell it you want to use the DataContext, you're saying you don't want to set the Source. It doesn't make sense to have both. Use DataContext and Path.

Comment: In a class you have a property with your items list. It could be any class, this is the idea that makes MVVM work. You then set that class as DataContext. Now you can set the property as path.

Answer (score 1):

You rarely need to use the data context of a control outside of the control. The most common use case for setting `DataContext`(`DataContext = this;`) is within `UserControl`'s code-behind to make all controls within the `UserControl` to bind to the control's properties.

When you use a `ListBox`, setting `ItemsSource` is sufficient, unless you are doing something funky.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good walkthrough: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=315275

Specifically, you need to set the `DataContext` first to tell it where to look for the `ItemsSource`. The easiest way is to set this on the Window through the XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <controllers:DownloadManager />
</Window.DataContext>
```